# How do I use node modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm, npm-install

Sorry for the basic question. I'm new to coding and I've already googled "how to run code from node modules" "how to use code from node modules" etc. for a few hours without any real progress.

Basically, I want to create a editable div with the text editor (https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor) and I already manually downloaded and followed the directions to inserting the code inside the editor (can be found on the GitHub page). 
Here is my code for the editable div in its entirety:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="post.css">
<script src="other.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/medium-editor.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default.css">
<script src="js/medium-editor.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" class= ".editable" id="posteditor"> <p> test words</p></div>
</body>
```

Javascript (other.js -referenced in html code):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.editable'),
editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');
```

I also copy and pasted the files from the downloaded file into a new file folder holding the HTML/CSS/Javascript code for the editable div (not sure if this even makes a difference). 
Thank you so much for helping a new coder. 
EDIT: Figured it out! My paths were in the wrong order and I wasn't referencing some of the necessary code in the

Answer (score 0):

You need some simple html css js basics knowledge to start dealing with such code

**here are some tips:**

*put `link` tag in the head

*put `script` tags in before the ending of the body

try now to run this code and double tap the word you want to edit

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/medium-editor/latest/css/medium-editor.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="editable"><h4>hi I am editable</h4></div>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/medium-editor/latest/js/medium-editor.min.js"></script>
    <script>var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have a few followup questions for you:

Comment: I am very happy that helped

Comment: -how did you know that the class was "editable" and not ".editable"?
-do you know how I can use the manual installation? I'm asking because I would like to change the formatting and style a bit and I assume that I'll need the files in my own server in order to change the code. Thank you so much!

Comment: `.editable` is a selector not class name but any class name shouldn't start with dot ... and what you want exactly to do with ur site I can't get why you want to use such plugin?

Comment: I want to change the look of the text editor (ie. add more features) and I think (?) that I would need to download the files into my server so that I can change them on my end.

Comment: Also, this doesn't run with my server (ie. putting into Sublime, saving it as a html file, opening in browser)

Comment: ^nvrmd, it's because I don't have jsDelivr, sorry!